# Function for click events

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseclick-event

I want to implement Nine Men's Morris Game.
I have a board with 24 pictureboxes and on the left and right side, 9 red pictureboxes and 9 green pictureboxes.
I want to add them in a list:

```
 List<PictureBox> ls = new List<PictureBox>();
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
            p.Name = "pictureBox" + i;
            ls.Add(p);
        }

    }
```

is it ok?

and is it possible to do something like this: I want to click on one of the 24 pictureboxes, and make the background of that picturebox to become one time green and one time red?
I mean recursive function or something like that that can recognize when i click on a picturebox, search in the list for that picturebox and changes his backcolor?

[image]

Comment: are you happy to use Javascript

Comment: no..i don't know Javascript

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any pictureBox list here.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
     PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
     p.Click += p_Click;
     //of course, somecontrol.Controls.Add(p);
     //for ex: this.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

-

```
void p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems you are trying to add an event handler to all pictureBoxes

```
**parentControl**.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                 .ToList().ForEach(p => p.Click+=p_Click);
```

Comment: not working... Is it ok how I added the pictureboxes to list? they already exist on the design

Comment: @LuciC Of course it is working. If you want to use the PictureBoxes you added at design time, then loop over them and add the event handler.

Comment: @LuciC Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to ask. What happens when you put that code in `Form1_Load` method?

Comment: so, I have 24 pictureboxes on the form...I want to add the event handler..but I do not want to write 24 times :"PictureBox 1.Click", "PictureBox2.Click"...I want something recursive that adds them to a list..

Comment: @LuciC But in your question, you create 24 pictureboxes dynamically(not in desing time (`PictureBox p = new PictureBox()`)). So your question has changed.

Comment: almost there.... please notice, I have 24 +9+9 pictureboxes and I want to add the event handler only to 24

Comment: `almost there`? me or you? I know how to write that kind of code. Maybe you should show some effort and try to understand what is going on. **Forget my answer**

Comment: you...I asked here because i don't know how to do it... i understood what you explained but please, read again my question... It's not that simple... Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

I assume the list of 24 PictureBoxes is supposed to represent the points on a nine man morris board where the player's men can be positioned.

I4V is right that all you need to do is add a click handler to each picture box. If you want to have the background alternate between green and red, keep your original list, but add the click handler in it

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Name = "pictureBox" + i;
    p.Click += p_Click; // <----------
    ls.Add(p);
}
```

And modify i4v's click handler to use the current background color to determine the new background color.

```
void p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender);
    p.BackColor = p.BackColor == Color.Green ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
}
```

A couple of other points.

- You don't set an initial background color, so it will be the default color until clicked on, when it will be set to Green (as Green isn't the default background color).
- Why name your pictureboxes w/ their List index + 1? Why not just use the List index and the natural C# iteration from 0: `for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)`?

Comment: I added the pictureboxes manually on the design, so the start from "pictureBox1"...etc   i undestood that the piece of code i wrote here is for adding them programatically...so it's not what i want..I already have thema nd need to put them in  a list... I can't assign the click event for all pictureboxes because i have more than 24, and i only need an event handler for those 24

Comment: So you're saying those picture boxes are specified in xaml? Why can't you specify the click handler for each one in xaml also?

Comment: no, they are on the form..i put them with drag and drop...but now it's ok... thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

The method you have outlined would not work, however there is another way to do the same thing using the `sender` object passed into the event handler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
        p.Name = "pictureBox" + i;
        p.Click += PictureBox_Click;
    }
}

void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox event_picturebox = (PictureBox)sender;
    event_picturebox.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

You just have to map every picture box you want to run this event to the same event, the event will then be able to perform actions on this pictureBox because a reference to it was passed in.

If you already have the picture boxes defined in the form, you just need to do something like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Click += PictureBox_Click;
    pictureBox2.Click += PictureBox_Click;
    // and keep going

    // OR
    // this is a bit dangerous if you don't want ALL 
    // your picture boxes to have this event
    // also assumes that you know picturebox1 exists.
    foreach (object f in this.Controls)
    {
        if (f.GetType().Equals(pictureBox1.GetType()))
        {
            ((PictureBox)f).Click += button_Click;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's ook how i added them to the list? they already exist on to the design

Comment: what if I want to do this for a limited time? saying 18 times...so that i change only 18 pictureboxes? then make another click event that will do some checkings...is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can remap the event at any time, but this doesn't seem to be the best way to do things, are you sure you want this all on the click event? why not make a button that will do all the checking when its clicked?

Comment: please, notice the details i gave in the initial question...I need to code a game.. i had 2 options 24 buttons that were clicked or 24 pictureboxes... All the checkings/actions are done when the pictureboxes are clicked

Comment: probably would be best to only map the picture boxes to one event and do all processing within that event, whether that involves an `if` that calls different methods or some other way. I would use the one liner at the bottom of the other answer though, it is quite sexy.